# How to filter a specific exception from Log4j?

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, log4j, java-8

I'm implementing some new features of Java 8 on my desktop app and Hibernate 3.6 seems to doesn't like it.

I added to an Interface a "default method", since then Hibernate it throwing:

```
2014-10-02 14:01:25,538 WARN entity.PojoEntityTuplizer  - could not create proxy factory for:modelo.ChequeTercero
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Javassist Enhancement failed: modelo.ChequeTercero
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:169)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: modelo/ChequeTercero_$$_javassist_45, method: _d21getNumeroValor signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
```

for EACH class that implement the interface multiplied for EACH default method in the interface.

As this log is a `Level.WARN`, it is generating biiiiiiiiiig log file on the users every time they open the application.

I tried to make some logger filters but is not working:

```
<filter class="org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.BasicLazyInitializer">
<param name="LevelMin" value="FATAL" />
<param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
        <param name="expression" value="EXCEPTION ~= org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.BasicLazyInitializer"/>
        <param name="acceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
        <param name="StringToMatch" value="org.hibernate.HibernateException: Javassist Enhancement failed"/>
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false" />
    </filter>
    <!--<filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/> -->
```

What am I doing wrong? Also if I uncomment `DenyAllFilter` no log appears anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the solution - [`RegexFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/RegexFilter.html).

Here is the related Log4j 2.x configuration, that allows me to exclude specific messages both from *log file* and *console* appenders.

```xml
<Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="System.out">
        <RegexFilter regex=".*(Javassist Enhancement failed|could not create proxy factory for).*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-2p %c{1.} %x - %m%n"/> 
    </Console>
    <File name="logfile" filename="./app.log" append="true">
        <!--Evita cargar en el log el error que tira hibernate por Java 8 (default method en Interfaces)-->
        <RegexFilter regex=".*(Javassist Enhancement failed|could not create proxy factory for).*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{-1} %X{userName} - %m%n"/> 
    </File>
</Appenders>
```

Answer (score 9):

Using log4j 1.2 I am able to filter out specific exceptions, using an [ExpressionFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/filter/ExpressionFilter.html) in the Appender.

```
<appender name="LOGFILE" class="com.me.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="..." />
    ...
    <layout .../>
    <!-- Exclude expected exceptions -->
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
        <param name="Expression" value="EXCEPTION ~= 'String found in the exception message'"/>
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

See http://blog.trifork.com/2011/08/23/filtering-specific-exceptions-when-using-log4j/

Answer (score 0):

> For YAML ,please see/read below:

The accepted answer is using [RegexFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/RegexFilter.html) and is an elegant solution for managing log filtering in Log4j2.

While implementing, encountered a scenario where it was needed to exclude a specific `Hibernate` error from being logged. As in our projects we are working with a `YAML` configuration, thus found it valuable to share the approach here, especially since most available examples on the internet tend to focus on `XML` configuration.

Below is an example of how to employ the `RegexFilter` within a `YAML` `Log4j2` configuration:

```
  Loggers:
    logger:
      - name: org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.batch
        level: ERROR
        Filters:
          # Ignore log events with 'org.hibernate.StaleStateException' exception
          - RegexFilter:
              regex: ".*org.hibernate.StaleStateException.*"
              onMatch: DENY
              onMismatch: NEUTRAL
```

In the above example, the intent is to filter out logs related to `org.hibernate.StaleStateException`, preventing them from being recorded. This is achieved while allowing all other `error` logs from the `org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.batch` logger to be captured.

Feel free to customize it further according to your preference.